# Using fetch in a loop in code by zapier

Tags: zapier

I want to do 3 different api call from my zapier code, get their returns in variables and merge them. I can't figure out how to do that. It will be like:

```
var urls = [apiUrl1, apiUrl2, apiUrl3];
var output = [];

for ( i = 0; i < urls.length; i++ ) {
    output[i] = fetch( urls[i] );
}
```

This is an example code. I can't get response to output, it gets only a blank object {}. What will be the procedure to save the fetch return values in the output array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things you'll need to brush up on:

1. Promises - especially Promise.all() - there is lots out there about that.
2. Callback to return the data asynchronously. Our help docs describe this.

The main reason your code fails is because you are assuming the fetch happens immediately. In JavaScript that is not the case - it happens Async and you have to use promises and callbacks to wait until they are done before returning the output via the callback!

Answer (score 7):

Since apparently the folks at Zapier do not like to give out working examples or any sort of decent documentation for this level of code intricacy... here is a working example:

```
var promises = [];

for (var i = urls.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    promises.push(fetch(urls[i]));
}

Promise.all(promises).then(function(res){
    var blobPromises = [];
    for (var i = res.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        blobPromises.push(res[i].text());
    }
    return Promise.all(blobPromises);
}).then(function(body){
    var output = {id: 1234, rawData: body};
    callback(null, output);
}).catch(callback);
```

This may not be the cleanest solution, but it works for me. Cheers!

Comment: I get: Promise.all is not a function

Comment: @Eric - 1. Are you attempting to run this as a javascript code action within a zap? Zapier should still have built-in support for Promise.all(). If you are attempting this outside of Zapier, then you would need to add Promise package as a requirement https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise. 2. Promise.all() expects an array. Are you passing in an array to Promise.all()? 3. If neither 2 or 3, then I would need more information on your usage.

Comment: @Eric - I just reran the above example with no issue. Promise.all() expects an array. Are you passing an array to Promise.all()?